# Downloading a .csv format file from a website

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am looking to automate a process at work, which has a step that requires me to go to a website, download data into a csv format, and then do the work and email out. I have written a set of macros that does most of this for me, however, I am having trouble understanding how to download data after navigating to the website (i see a few tutorials where the given website is already in excel format).  Basically, you navigate to website, click drop-down menu, and pick export option.

I have the following script currently, and it gets me to the correct page. But I need to click on an "export" button and then an ".csv" format button once I get to this page. Does anyone have any advice, solutions or tutorials that I can look at?

```
'method to open chrome, collect Jira report and download it to folder
Sub getJiraReport()

Dim chromePath As String

chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

'loads the Jira Page with report
Shell (chromePath & " -url https://companyname.atlassian.net/issues/?    filter=10600")

End Sub
```

Comment: Advice - Use `IE` if you have it. VBA cannot manipulate chrome. There is information on the web though about how to do this.

Comment: You could follow the calls the website makes when working with the developer tools of Chrome.  In the network tab you should see the call go out to retrieve the csv formatted document. This url is probably what you want to use again if possible (or allowed by the website...)

Comment: You can Try the Selenium VBA which will allow you to automate Chrome and Firefox browsers.This link can give you a heads up http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think you're right.  If you happen to know a good tutorial meant for new(ish) users, let me know.  Thank you for the help.